# Close current browser tab using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**How to close current browser using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

> (close tab that is not generated using javascript)

As a security mesure, most recent browser won't allow you to do that at all, so you can't make something a user wouldn't want.